# How to search for civi contacts who don't have a Joomla user account

Tags: contacts, search

Is there a way within the civiCRM GUI to search for just those contacts who do or do not have an associated Joomla user account?

Answer (score 3):

Found it: the option exists under the Advanced Search: CMS User?

Comment: Correct. I also just create a smart group from that search, so that I can ID current members that did not set up a user account when they joined.